# OP name suddenly got background?

Tags: discussion, design, original-poster

Well..  [image]

I can swear it didn't have background only couple of hours ago and can't find any trace of such a change in here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

So, is this new silent change or am I just getting old?

For the record, I do like it. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been this way since [August 23, 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my aging! :D